# What will happen if Thread object disappears before thread routine finishes?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a question about thread objects.
Let's say I made a new Thread object on 'pendingThread' executing 'NewThread()' method and started it.
NewThread() method takes quite a lot of time to return. What happens if 'pendingThread' is reinitialized before previously started thread returns?
Will it Abort or suspend?

It will be a pleasure to see you answers

```
    public void Threaded_accept()//this function accepts client. It's executed on the new thread
    {
        bool pending = this.listen_socket.AcceptAsync(this.accept_args);// If completed Asynchronously
        //On_Accept_Completed is called Automatically

        if (pending == false)// If AcceptAsync was completed synchronously
        {

            this.pendingThread = new Thread(StartNewThread);
            pendingThread.Start();//This is for keep receiving requests while Thread is working
            //TODO What happens when pendingThread is reinitialized while pending Thread was running?
        }

        flow_control_event.WaitOne();//wait until scoket is accepted

    }
```

Comment: A Thread object can't disappear while it is executing code.  Unlike normal .NET objects, no object reference is needed since the CLR itself is aware of it.  It knows when a thread starts and stops executing code.  Notable as well is that Thread does not have a Dispose() method, even though it uses 5 unmanaged OS objects.  Different for Task objects, they also can't disappear, but done with an actual object reference.  Stored on the stack, the GC always finds it back.

Answer (score 2):

Foreground threads keep running until they exit normally (by returning from the function given as the thread start function) or abnormally (due to an exception, including the possibility of an exception injected from elsewhere via `Thread.Abort`) or when the entire process gets torn down.<sup>1</sup>

You don't need to keep a reference to a particular `Thread` object around to make this happen.

---

<sup>1</sup>Background threads are really the same, just worth bearing in mind that when all of the Foreground threads have exited, that can be one of the reasons why the entire process is being torn down.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, garbage collector would check if he thread if the thread is still running or not, Even reference to Thread object is not present. Which means only exited thread will be destroyed by garbage collector.